# webrtc speed issues when i capture screen

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, p2p

am developing a 4 peers webrtc video chat! 
everything is fine at this point , so i add a screen sharing future to the website!

when ever i press screenshare ,  the connection becomes so slow ! i thought it's because 4 peers connection  , but this happens only when i share my screen .
i tried to use RemoveStream function that sends the camera stream, but the streams still lagging .
this is the function that runs after i press screenshare button

```
async function startCapture() {

  var audioStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true});
  var audioTrack = audioStream.getAudioTracks()[0];

  let captureStream = null;

  try {
    captureStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(gdmOptions);
    captureStream.addTrack( audioTrack );

  } catch(err) {
    console.error("Error: " + err);
  }
//   return captureStream;


  if(rtcPeerConn){
    rtcPeerConn.removeStream(myStream);

      rtcPeerConn.addStream(captureStream);

  }
  if(rtcPeerConn1){
    rtcPeerConn1.removeStream(myStream);

      rtcPeerConn1.addStream(captureStream);

  }  
  if(rtcPeerConn2){
    rtcPeerConn2.removeStream(myStream);

       rtcPeerConn2.addStream(captureStream);

  }  
  if(rtcPeerConn3){
    rtcPeerConn3.removeStream(myStream);

       rtcPeerConn3.addStream(captureStream);

  }
  myStream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
        track.stop();
      });
  myStream = captureStream;
  success(myStream);
}
```

i even tried to remove tracks from the first stream like this

```
async function startCapture() {
  myStream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
        track.stop();
      });

  var audioStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true});
  var audioTrack = audioStream.getAudioTracks()[0];

  let captureStream = null;

  try {
    captureStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(gdmOptions);
    captureStream.addTrack( audioTrack );

  } catch(err) {
    console.error("Error: " + err);
  }


  if(rtcPeerConn){
    rtcPeerConn.removeStream(myStream);

      rtcPeerConn.addStream(captureStream);

  }
  if(rtcPeerConn1){
    rtcPeerConn1.removeStream(myStream);

      rtcPeerConn1.addStream(captureStream);

  }  
  if(rtcPeerConn2){
    rtcPeerConn2.removeStream(myStream);

       rtcPeerConn2.addStream(captureStream);

  }  
  if(rtcPeerConn3){
    rtcPeerConn3.removeStream(myStream);

       rtcPeerConn3.addStream(captureStream);

  }

  myStream = captureStream;
  success(myStream);
}
```

as you see i used removeStream function to avoid sending useless streams , but still nothing changed.

Comment: Adding and removing streams isn't giving you the control you want, which is why the API has [moved to tracks](https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/the-evolution-of-webrtc/). [removeStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/removeStream) is deprecated and doesn't even work in Firefox or Safari. FYI

Answer (score 1):

What are the constraints you are placing on `getDisplayMedia`?  Perhaps you are sending "too much" video content, and thus slowing everything down.

[edit]

According to your comment, you are recording audio from the screen, and also audio from the mic. Perhaps remove the audio track from the screen recording?

You can also use options to reduce the size of the video: (this requires using `getUserMedia` instead of `getDisplayMedia`)

```
video:{
            width: { min: 100, ideal: width, max: 1920 },
            height: { min: 100, ideal: height, max: 1080 },
            frameRate: {ideal: framerate}
        }
```

Perhaps a lower framerate?  Try reducing the size and see if that helps too :)

Comment: const gdmOptions = {
  video: {
    cursor: "always"
  },
  audio: {
    echoCancellation: true,
    noiseSuppression: true,
    sampleRate: 44100
  }
}
this is from the MDN website

Comment: Thank you alot, this could be usefull , making less frames , but i can't remove audio track from screen recording , i need it.
when i start sharing my screen i delete the camera track , so they other peers won't hear me if i don't attach the audio to screen share

Comment: This answer is incorrect and [gives](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/q75yb8pf/66/) `TypeError: min constraints are not supported`. There's no device discovery in `getDisplayMedia`, just downscaling, so `min` and `exact` constraints aren't needed. Just specify the size you want, e.g. `{width: 640, height: 480, frameRate: 10}`.

Comment: The Min constraints work for getUserMedia, but not getUserDisplayMedia